# Where are the different terms for sandwich (emparedado, sándwich, bocadillo etc) used?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, comida

It's hard to know which word should be used in which country.

Some countries use only one term, some others use 2 or 3 with different meanings, and some other ones give one of the terms another meaning or even the opposite meaning.

It becomes very hard to understand.

I already know that "sándwich" is used in Spain (and in most countries), but not "emparedado".

In Spain, it seems that they have the two words "sándwich" and "bocadillo", but not with the same kind of sandwich -- so what's the difference and how did it come about, etymologically?

There's also "sanduche", "sanguche" (Guatemala, Argentina), "sangüich", etc.

Comment: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=sándwich

Comment: Bocadillo is a small mouthful and sandwich is from the Earl of Sandwich.

Comment: Why don't you try using the RAE??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Diccionario de Americanismos, the following are generic terms for sandwiches:

- [sánduich](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=s%C3%A1nduich) (RD, Ch)
- [sánduche](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=s%C3%A1nduche) (Co, Ve, Ec)
- [sanduche](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=sanduche) (Ve)
- [sánguche](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=s%C3%A1nguche) (Ni, CR, Ve, Ch, Ar, Ur) (Pe)
- [sángüiche](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=s%C3%A1ng%C3%BCiche) (RD, Ur)
- [torta](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=torta) (Mx)

And in Spain:

- [bocadillo](https://dle.rae.es/bocadillo), [bocata](https://dle.rae.es/bocata) (a sandwich made with baguette/any bread)
- [sándwich](https://dle.rae.es/s%C3%A1ndwich) (a sandwich made with sandwich bread)

Note that some terms may refer to specific types of sandwich/specific fillings in certain regions.

Comment: Any particular reason you didn't want to add to the community wiki answer I started?  That's how we usually handle questions of this type.  Otherwise things can get really messy with a dozen different answers.

Comment: In Mexico **torta** and **sándnwich** are not he same thing. It's similar to the case you posted with Spain. Also in Mexico the we call **pastel** to what other countries call **torta**. An also **tortilla** in Mexico is different from the **tortilla** in Spain.

Answer (score 1):

In Spain you use bocadillo for a baguette-looking piece of bread with something inside it. Common as school lunch or on trips. Bocata is synonymous/slang for the same thing.

A sándwich is a typical American sandwich. A square flat piece of bread, often with ham and cheese in it.

Comment: mazunki, thanks for posting the information about Spain.  Would you do me a favor and transfer it to the Community Wiki post?  Generally, when we are trying to cover the entire Spanish-speaking world, we use a Community Wiki post for everything.  Otherwise, things get too messy.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- México: torta (tradicional), sándwich (por la influencia de EEUU)
- España: sándwich, bocadillo